# Use htacess to rewrite URL that is a CNAME

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cname

In my DNS settings I added a CNAME record.  Example:

location.mywebsite.com CNAME >>  someurl.com

This works as expected and the content from someurl.com loads fine, and the domain in the address bar shows location.mywebsite.com.  However, I want to be able to use mywebsite.com/location to show the URL. Really not sure what the .htacess rule for that should be.  I tried various exampled online but without any success, or maybe I'm looking at it all wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what do you want to achieve. When user enters `mywebsite.com/location` in address bar, which page do you want to show and do you want url in address bar to change (and if so, change to what)?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion and the late reply.  If the url address bar is location.mywebsite.com the CNAME record will show someurl.com.  This works as intended and I need to keep it like that, but I want to show mywebsite.com/location in the url address bar.